# ''Launch MainActivity'' code prevents texts from displaying

Tags: java, android, eclipse, background, sms

My original app receives a text and uses character split to split and display in textviews. I have then implemented codes to invoke an activity from BroadcastReceiver so the activity is brought to the front when a texts is received, but the app's textviews are not updating.

If i remove from SMSReceiver.java , it works normally but the app is not brought to the front.

```
//--Launch the MainActivity--//
        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        mainActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
```

SMSReceiver.java code:

```
package com.example.smssend;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {


//--Get the SMS Message passed in---//
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null)
        {


//--Retrieve the SMS message received--//
            Object[] pdus = (Object[] ) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
            {


msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();


}
            //--Display the new SMS Message--//
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String sender = null;



//--Launch the MainActivity--//
            Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);


mainActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);


    //--Send a broadcast intent to update the SMS received in the activity--//


    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
            context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably when you send your broadcastIntent the Activity has not been loaded or binded to any receiver yet.

You can avoid the problem passing the message in your mainActivityIntent instead of using a broadcastIntent to update the Activity.

You can recover the intent using getIntent() in the Activity and then update the UI.

```
Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
mainActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mainActivityIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
context.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
```

In your Activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
            super.onResume();
            Intent myIntent = getIntent();
            String sms = myIntent.getStringExtra("sms");
            if (sms != null && !"".equals(sms))
            {
                            mTextView.setText(sms);
            }
    }
```

hope, it helps :)

Comment: I added your onResume() part to my MainActivity.java:
However the textviews are still not displaying. 

    @Override
     protected void onResume(){
      super.onResume();
      Intent myIntent = getIntent();
      String sms = myIntent.getStringExtra("sms");
      if (sms != null && !"".equals(sms))
            {
           

         TextView mTextView = null;
     mTextView.setText(sms);
    }
 //--Register the receiver--//
 registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
 super.onResume();
}

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.smssend;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Button btnSendSMS;
IntentFilter intentFilter;
String textView1;
String textView2;
String textView3;

private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        //--Display the SMS received in the TextView1--//

        TextView SMSes3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
        TextView SMSes2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView SMSes1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = intent.getExtras().getString("sms");
        char arr[] = textView3.toCharArray();
        String String1 = new String(arr);
        String[] parts = String1.split(" ");
        String part1 = parts[0];
        String part2 = parts[1];
        String part3 = parts[2];
        SMSes2.setText(part2);
        SMSes1.setText(part1);
        SMSes3.setText(part3);

    }
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //--Intent to filter for SMS messages received--//
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            sendSMS("92200026", "Hello");
        }


    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    //--Register the receiver--//
    registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    //--Unregister the receiver--//
    unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

//--Send an SMS message to another device---//
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}